# search column in other column sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Table1 . *
FROM
    Table1
        inner JOIN
    Table2 ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2
```

I want to change the query to find NOT only a macth between `Table1.Column1` to `Table2.Column2` but to find all data where `Table1.Column1` is a string inside `Table2.Column2`.

What I need to do?

Comment: just noticed this is tagged mysql and sql-server, which is it?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
SELECT 
    Table1 . *
FROM
    Table1
        inner JOIN
    Table2 ON Table1.Column1 LIKE CONCAT('%',Table2.Column2,'%')
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's `SQL SERVER`, use `CHARINDEX`

```
SELECT 
Table1 . *
FROM
Table1
    inner JOIN
Table2 ON CHARINDEX(Table1.Column1, Table2.Column2) > 0
```

Comment: What is the  > 0 for at the end of the query?

Comment: CHARINDEX retuns 0 if it is not able to find the specified text in the string to be searched. If the text is found, it returns the position of that text. > 0 ensures that only those record combinations are displayed where Table1.Column1 is found in Table2.Column2

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ON` clause to

SqlServer

```
ON Table2.Column2 LIKE '%'+Table1.Column1+'%'
```

MySQL

```
ON Table2.Column2 LIKE CONCAT('%',Table1.Column1,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    Table1.*
FROM
    Table1
        inner JOIN
    Table2 ON T Table2.Column2 Like '%' + Table1.Column1 + '%'
```